Unable to add color to the pointer(marker) in mapbox map flutter
I am unable to add color to the marker in mapbox map
I've used mapbox_maps_flutter: ^2.3.0 plugin to load pointer(marker),and Everything is working perfact but when I set marker color, It always take black color and don't take given color.
Please If you have used color in pointer(marker) then please answer this question.
I have provided code to add marker to the mapbox map below.
 List<mapbox.PointAnnotationOptions> markerOptions = [];

  void addToMarkerOptions(MarkerModel marker) {
    var tempPointAnnotations = mapbox.PointAnnotationOptions(
      geometry: mapbox.Point(
        coordinates: mapbox.Position(
          marker.longitude ?? 0,
          marker.latitude ?? 0,
        ),
      ),
      iconSize: 1.8,
      image: marker.rowImage,//Uint8List Image
      textColor: marker.selectedColor,
      iconColor: Colors.red.value,
      iconHaloColor: marker.selectedColor,
    );
    markerOptions.add(
      tempPointAnnotations,
    );
  }

For showing multiple marker in mapbox I've used createMulti method.
  pointAnnotationManager?.createMulti(markerOptions);

Please let me know in comment If you need any further detail from me.

Please refer example app of mapbox
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-flutter/tree/main/example
And Example app is without public key and secret key so you have to use your keys in that app
